# restrict the redirection to login page once the user has already logged in even if he press the back button of browser in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to make  a login page which check the conditon and user is redirected to home page afterwards , now i want to implement a condition that when user has visited home page and he clicks on the back button or browser he should'nt be able to again visit login page . i tried to set a variable isLogged in as false and after checking the username and password make that variable to true and store that in local storage and use it like flag , but i am not able to properly get where's m wrong .

here is my app.js

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp',['ngRoute','ngStorage']);
var loggedIn = false;
validationApp.run(function($rootScope, $localStorage){
  //var loggedIn = false;
    //if(!loggedIn) {
        storage = window.localStorage;
        //storage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
        //console.log(storage.getItem("loggedIn"));
//    $rootScope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
//        loggedIn: false
//    })
//    }
});

validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope,loginservice,$localStorage) {
    $scope.dologin = function () {
        //storage.setItem("loggedIn" ,true);
        //loginsucess = storage.getItem("loggedIn");

        if(loggedIn == false) {
            //console.log(loginsucess);
            if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
                loginservice.login($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password);
            }
            storage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
        }
    }
});
```

i tried to put a check condition into my routes also and now i am not able to get my home page even after valid credentials .

```
validationApp.config(

    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'main.html',
                controller: 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                resolve:{
                    "check":function($location){
                        if(storage.getItem(loggedIn) == true)
                        {
                            alert(loggedIn);
                            $location.path("/home");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $location.path("/main");
                        }
                    }
                },
                controller: 'mainController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
});


validationApp.service('loginservice',function($location)
{
    this.login = function(username, password){
        console.log(username,password);

        if(username == "ank@gmail.com" && password=="1234")
        {
            //alert('thank you for submitting your form');
            $location.path("/home");

            //console.log(storage.getItem("loggedIn"));
        }
        else
        {
          //alert("invalid username and password");
            $location.path("/main");

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/46O0znC5HFDE4cYXSm5h?p=preview

Stored data in cookies in login function as follows,

```
$cookies.userinfo = {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'pqr'
};
```

And on logout remove that data -

```
delete $cookies.userinfo;
```

then check for 'angular.isDefined($cookies.userinfo)' (userinfo is cookie name which given at the time of storing data in it) if find then redirect it to your page which you want to see after login. i.e

```
app.run(function ($cookies) {
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
        if (angular.isDefined($cookies.userinfo)) {
            $location.path("/pathname");
        }

      });
});
```

Comment: i want to store my things in local storage only

Answer (score 0):

See if this serves your purpose

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp',  ['ngRoute','ngStorage']);

    var loggedIn = false;
    validationApp.run(function($rootScope, $localStorage, $location){

       storage = window.localStorage;
       $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (evt, next, current) {

           if(storage.getItem(loggedIn) == true) {
                if (next.$$route.originalPath == '/login')
                    $location.path('/home');
           }
           else
             $location.path('/login');
       });


});
```

Comment: it is giving me this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$on' of undefined , and i am not aware of what actually $on does??

Comment: Actually i have written $rootscope two times , now it should work

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…lace%3D!1%3Breturn%20q%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%2011%3B%20oldVal%3A%2010%22%5D%5D
    at Error (native)

Comment: are there any other dependencies for $rootscope?? or i am missing defining it somewhere else??

Comment: i have made a working example , please refer to it. http://plnkr.co/edit/ID9YslW8RmOzB9t19Dq6?p=preview

Comment: one more thing i would like to ask once the code runs i am not able to see my login page even after page refresh nd browser is closed what if i want to run it again ?? i should make a logout button for that ??

Comment: yes  and in the logout function you should clear the variable from localstorage using `storage.removeItem('loggedIn');`

Comment: you can also manually remove from localstorage using chrome developer tools

Comment: sorry it requires 15 reputation i am new to stackoverflow i am not able to mark it correct .